# Where is the cabin air recirc intake?

Tags: ac, cleaning, buick, interior, lacrosse

Background: I am trying to remove a slight smoke smell from a 2014 Buick LaCrosse. I am taking several steps to get the smell out. This question is really only focused on one of those steps.

Here is what I would like to do:

1. Turn on the A/C with recirculation ON.
2. Spray Febreze into the air inlet so that it helps to deodorize the inside of the vent system.

I don't know where to spray for step 2! Where should I look for that air intake? The only guidance I have found online talks about the intake for air coming from the outside. (Sounds like it is typically at the base of the windshield on the outside of the vehicle.) But since there is a recirculation feature, there must be an intake somewhere inside the cabin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it will be in the front footwell and you will recognise it as it usually has a grill. Stops paper etc being drawn in.

Comment: It didn't have a grate but there was air flowing in around where the brake and gas pedals attach to the car. I found a black plastic manifold that looks like it might be the air intake. But it started blowing out air when I moved the air to the foot blowers. On the passenger side there were rectangle holes with rounded corners. Some were intake and some were exhaust. I checked the air direction with a half inch by 4 inch strip of paper. Thanks!